# What are the manacled or shackled combat modifiers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

Two fighters escape from a prisoner transfer. They are essentially identical, except one has manacles around his wrists while the other has shackles around his ankles.

What are the modifiers to the attack rolls for each  fighter? Are they the same modifier?

Do both fighters have the Entangled condition? The Grappled condition? Some other condition?

Answer (score 4):

The term you're looking for for someone bound by the ankles is "fetters", defined in the "Melee Tactics Toolbox".  Fetters entangle in addition to the below:

> **Fetters**: These manacles are specifically designed to fit around the ankles, and use the same rules for breaking, escape, and cost relative to size. **A creature in fetters is entangled** and can move at only half speed. In addition, a fettered creature must succeed at a DC 15 Acrobatics check to move more than its (reduced) speed in a round. If it fails the check by 5 or more, the creature falls prone.

For the manacles around the wrists, there are separate mechanics if they're bound with their hands in front or in back (same book as above).  No extra conditions are implied however.

> **Frontal Restraint**: A creature whose wrists are bound with manacles can wield only one melee weapon or shield in combat (the weapon may be a two-handed weapon). It cannot make use of ranged weapons, except for crossbows (but even these cannot be reloaded by the bound creature). Any attack the creature makes while manacled takes a –4 penalty. The creature can attempt skill checks using its hands, but at a –5 penalty (–15 on Disable Device checks to pick the lock of manacles the creature is wearing).
>
> **Rear Restraint**: Manacles might be employed to keep a creature’s hands behind its back. In such cases, the creature cannot use its hands to effectively employ any weapon or shield. The creature can attempt to use its hands to perform a skill, but at a –10 penalty (–25 on Disable Device checks to pick the lock of manacles the creature is wearing). While manacled, a creature can attempt to flip its arms beneath its legs, bringing its hands in front of itself. This requires a successful DC 25 Escape Artist check (a separate Escape Artist check is then required to escape the manacles).

You can choose DM discretion to give them those conditions instead if you don't want to work with the mechanics above.

Comment: Your quote of the fetters states "A creature in fetters is entangled". Isn't that the [entangled](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/Gamemastering/conditions/#Entangled) condition as asked in the question?

Comment: I'd say no because it doesn't say they gain the "ensnared" condition like other effects.  For example, the Entangle spell specifies "the target [that fails a save] gains the entangled condition".  I chalk it up to limited synonyms for "ensnared".

Comment: Actually, scratch that.  Some spells don't specify they gain a condition but imply it (like Snare), so I'd let the GM decide which way to rule, siding in favor of gaining the condition.  I edited my answer to reflect your contribution.

Comment: I'm confused why you think the word entangled here would not mean the Entangled condition (other than perhaps its lack of capitalization which is not unique); there is no "Ensnared" Condition.

Comment: My phone's autocorrect put ensnare in, but I meant entangle in both instances.